# How do you ask a question that will get a "great question" badge?

Tags: discussion

I see a lot of questions that get high votes. Some of them are good, but a lot of them are just ordinary questions or even similar to older question. My question is this:

**Do people promote their question in some way?**

Comment: I'm casting my duplicate vote there because the answers to this question are going to tell you to ask good questions. People do not typically promote their questions, though occasionally a question ends up on reddit and is swamped with unnecessary upvotes. Either way, it comes down to asking a good question, to which I refer you to the SO question checklist.

Comment: No, sometimes a question just goes 'viral'. Someone *else* mentions it on Reddit, or something.

Comment: Often, it doesn't even have to be a *good* question—quite the contrary, you can ask a terrible question that shows zero effort, where just many other people  think, "Hey, I've been asking this myself as well…", so there you get your upvotes and views.